# How to hide Div tag without page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page where i add,edit and delete menus.For add and edit I have a separate page.When i add or edit menus,i come on the main page where i display the menus,so i print messages as "menu added" or "menu edited".But when i delete the menu,my page does not get refreshed,because i have written the delete code on the same page sing ajax function as follows:

```
$.ajax(
           {
               type: "POST",
                   url: "delete_menu.php",
                   data: data,
                  cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
               parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
               document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = '';
           }
        }
```

The page does not get refreshed,so the div containing messages like "menus added or edited" does not get hide.I have given id to Div as showDiv.
So can anyone help me to solve this problem.Also when i delete,can anyone tell me how do i display message as "menu deleted" in ajax without page refresh.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer your previous questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have referenced jQuery, I would use jQuery syntax instead of Plain Old JavaScript, to keep the syntax cleen.

```
 $("#showDiv").hide();
```

If you are not going to show the div again on the page, you could use this:

```
$("#showDiv").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('showDiv').style.display = 'none';
```